# Update an index of MongoDB array dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update any index of FirstCol array dynamically in Nodejs. How do I go about doing that in this collection.

```
   {
     "TableId": "0",
     "FirstCol": [
        "Have high energy ",
        "Talk more than listen "
     ]
    }
```

I know I can update a specific array index using the dot operator. For eg:

```
 db.testcol.update(
    { "TableId": "0" },
    { $set:
      {
        "FirstCol.1": "rain gear"
      }
     }
    )
```

But what if I did not know that I have to edit index 1 of array FirstCol. How to frame the update query in order to update the index of the array which is suppose in variable 'editIndex'.
Can I do something like:

```
db.testcol.update(
        { "TableId": "0" },
        { $set:
          {
            "FirstCol.editIndex": "rain gear"
          }
         }
        )
```

Need your help. Thanks :)

Comment: This works `db.arr.update({},{ $set: { "arr.0" : 'Your updated text' } }, {many:false})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with ES6 [**Computed Property Keys**](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/#computed-property-keys) method

```
db.testcol.update(
  { "TableId": "0" },
  { "$set": {
    ["FirstCol." + editIndex]: "rain gear"
  }},
  function(err, res) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res)
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Anthony I tried to execute the update query with a callback function like this:

    db.testcol.update(
      { "TableId": "0" },
     { "$set": {
     ["FirstCol." + editIndex]: "rain gear"
    }}
    ),function(err,res) {
     if(err) console.log("QUERY was not Successfully")
     else{
     console.log("QUERY Successfully");
     res.send('Edited');
    }
    }

The control is not going to the callback function at all.

Comment: Upddated the answer

Comment: Thank-you so much @Anthony. This worked. I've marked your answer correct also.